# "Children ask their mothers which hand to hold their chopsticks in"

Tags: verbs

If I want to say someone asked (something) can I use 言います, or must I use the proper verb?

> 子供はお母さんに「左か右、どっちのほうがいいですか？」と尋ねた。

Does the following make sense for reported speech? I'm not sure about the use of と as an article, if the verb is correct, or if the use of どっち is right in this context.

Comment: 聞く might be preferable to 尋ねる casually; used in this sense, it's sometimes spelt 訊く.

Comment: I personally think children would not use the polite words "です”, "ます” to their parents. So I think 「左か右，どっちのほうがいい？」 would sound better to me.

Comment: Thanks, does anyone know the difference between 問う and 聞く？

Comment: @PaulCunningham Better to ask that as a new question. You should probably add 訊ねる to the list as well.

Comment: The other link answered my question about reported speech, which seems much simpler in Japanese than in English (which explains why my students have such a hard time with reported speech in English!)